# Split ndarray into smaller ndarray stored in a list

Tags: python, numpy

I currently looking for method in which i can split a ndarray into smaller ndarrays.

example: given ndarray with shape (78,1440,3), from which i want to extract a list of smaller ndarrays of the size (78,72,3), that would be 20 smaller sub ndarrays.

I tried using `numpy.split`.

```
numpy.split(matrix,72,axis=1)
```

which generates a list of length 72
and  the first entry has the shape (78,20,3)..

Why am I not able to extract the size i need?

Comment: In a list or an `array`?

Comment: Because `72` is the **number of elements you split it into**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 72 in the `split` is the **number of elements** to split it into, not the **size** of the splitted dimensions (according to the axis).

You can however use:

```
numpy.split(matrix,matrix.shape[1]//72,axis=1)
```

to split it into 20 elements of length 72 (for your given case). Note that you have to ensure that the **`shape[1]` is dividable by 72** otherwise a `ValueError` will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach #1 :** You can use [`np.hsplit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html) made exactly for this task -

```
np.hsplit(arr,20) # creates list of 20 arrays
```

Sample run -

1) Input array :

```
In [52]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,6,3))

In [53]: a
Out[53]: 
array([[[7, 8, 8],
        [7, 7, 1],
        [1, 6, 4],
        [6, 3, 8],
        [4, 7, 4],
        [0, 6, 3]],

       [[0, 8, 5],
        [2, 2, 8],
        [6, 0, 7],
        [5, 4, 6],
        [4, 3, 1],
        [8, 6, 6]]])
```

2) Split axis=1 into `3` *parts*, thus each part/subarray would be of length `(2,2,3)` shape. Thus, we would get a list of those 3 arrays :

```
In [54]: b = np.hsplit(a,3)
```

3) Manually verify those parts :

```
In [55]: b[0]
Out[55]: 
array([[[7, 8, 8],
        [7, 7, 1]],

       [[0, 8, 5],
        [2, 2, 8]]])

In [56]: b[1]
Out[56]: 
array([[[1, 6, 4],
        [6, 3, 8]],

       [[6, 0, 7],
        [5, 4, 6]]])

In [57]: b[2]
Out[57]: 
array([[[4, 7, 4],
        [0, 6, 3]],

       [[4, 3, 1],
        [8, 6, 6]]])
```

**Approach #2 :** Another tool for this task would be [`np.array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) -

```
np.array_split(arr,20,axis=1)
```